# Run APK File in Flex Mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

I have an app that needs to be updated. To make the update, I'll download the app inside a directory of the user and then I'll need to open it. Well, that's the problem. I can't open the .apk in the mobile application, it does not allow to use the `openWithDefaultApplication` and neither have `NativeProcess`.

I've searched a lot for some ANE, but without lucky. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try [jakehilton's PackageManagerANE](https://github.com/jakehilton/PackageManagerANE) ...

Comment: Any idea of how can I use it in my project? Never worked with ANE before. Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: Take a look on [Using native extensions for Adobe AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html), that can help, then if you have any problem on how to use that ANE, you can post a question directly in [github](https://github.com/jakehilton/PackageManagerANE/issues/).

Comment: that's not how a apk should be updated, publish a new version that's all.

Comment: Thanks @akmozo!
@BotMaster I can't publish my app, it is not commercial.

Comment: If your use-case is so small-scale that publishing your app isn't right, you should be able to just manually update each device.

Comment: @Brian the people that will use the app never had smartphone before. It will be hard to they update the app. Its almost 200 smartphones with the app, update one by one manually will be bad.

Comment: If it's that scale, then you should publish the app as Botmaster said.  Out of curiosity, why don't you want to publish it in Google Play?

Comment: @Brian because the app has been developed for a specific client, and they don't want to publish in the Play Store.

Comment: @akmozo PackageManager search for my app in the Play Store. I need to open it on local folder.

Comment: Huh.  Strange requirement.  Well, good luck.

Comment: So first thing those 200 users should know is how to install an update of the app!! You could have had a button on your UI that says "check for updates" then it goes to some online server to save the file (check dates if newer than current APK). Once saved then a pop-up gives instructions on how to un-install old version adn re-install newer update